# Adding new terms in the Gosen Dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, lucene

How do you add new terms in the Gosen's Dictionary?

Comment: Tell Gosen his car is being towed, then use permanent marker.

Comment: Pardon, but I'm not familiar with the expression.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean Chasen?

Comment: I just googled. There's nothing out there called a 'Gosen' dictionary. Either this is about Chasen, or it's about something much too obscure.

Comment: I mean this project : https://itadaki.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/itadaki/GoSen/

Answer (score 0):

GoSen uses the IPAdic dictionary (it downloads it when you run the GoSen build script). I haven't had time to learn all the details, but directions on how to add stuff are located in the user's manual [here](http://fr.sourceforge.jp/projects/ipadic/docs/ipadic-2.7.0-manual-en.pdf/en/1/ipadic-2.7.0-manual-en.pdf.pdf)